# Polymer, observer for object property with numeric key

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, observers

How to observe an object property with numeric key, as:

```
"employees":[
     {"1": 0, "2":"John", "3":"Doe"}, 
     {"1": 1, "2":"Anna", "3":"Smith"},
]
```

Observing whole object works well with: `employees.*`

But can not target specific property as: `employees["2"]` .
How can specific property be targeted?

Here is [Plunk example](http://plnkr.co/edit/fM20MvKJyf7WxwF1PtZe?p=preview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To observe all changes to the 2nd employee in your example, you'd use [Deep sub-property changes on array items](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#key-paths):

```
observers: [
  'bigup(datatable.employees.#1.*)'
],
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kD3oeBzG9hKlVcGVEiWd?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

In order to have observer on deep property you can mention that property in observer `datatable.employees.2`. You can read more on it [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#deep-observation).

I've also updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/sSX4uiru4K3bdYQjaX83?p=preview)
 for you